# How to make parse online with ANTLR 4?

Tags: eclipse, antlr, codemirror

I search on a web IDE using ANTLR for my custom language ,But I can't find  so I try to build one using antlr 4 and codemirror editor,
 I need to parse online But I did't knew How to do it with antlr 4 , so can any body help me to knew How to make parse online with ANTLR 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try XText. It uses ANTLR internally, and can generate Web-based, Eclipse-based and IntelliJ-based editors.

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/